# out-of-line definition of 'tedt'

Tags: c++, function

Sorry if my English won't be clear for you, I'm a Russian student.

I have a code of a class with function declarations:

Account.h

```
class Account {
public:
    Account();
    virtual ~Account() = 0;
    void tedt(const std::string &);
    Account(std::string);
}
```

Account.cpp:

```
#include "Account.h"
void Account::tedt(const std::string& a) <===== error here
{
    return;
}

Account::Account()
{
    Account(""); <==== some other error is here...
}


Account::Account(std::string input) <===== and here!!!
{
    SetLogin(input);
    SetProxy("");
}
```

I see this message:

```
error: out-of-line definition of 'tedt' does not match any declaration in 'Account'
```

end this

```
error: out-of-line definition of 'Account' does not match any declaration in 'Account' (about Account::Account(std::string input))
```

And I don't know to do. I'm using qt creator for coding if it is important

Comment: You need to at least give us a [mcve].

Comment: There's a semicolon missing after class definition.

Comment: There is [ru.so] if you are more comfortable posting in Russian.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out, you need to put a semicolon after the closing bracket of your class definition.

Please also note that your constructor without arguments will not work as expected here. Instead, you create a new temporary object with the argument. This will not change your current object. Better use:

```
Account::Account() : Account("") {}
```

, which works as expected.